# Programatically add Spring interceptor without application desciptor

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, interceptor

I have an interceptor that I would like to invoke on all requests.
I would like to configure that interceptor without component-scan or adding it the `mvc:interceptors` element in the web.xml.

Is it possible?

Comment: Is that interceptor a spring component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, if you use Java Configuration.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this or reference me to some documentation? AFAIK Java Configuration will still require component scan.

Comment: Why don't you want to use mvc:interceptors ?

Comment: I'm providing a library that contains this interceptor, and I want to user the to do as little as possible in order to use the lib, i.e. just to add the lib without touching the configuration xml.